# paypal adaptive payments and ipn response

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have read a little bit about PayPal's Adaptive Payments.
And I'm thinking of implementing this method in a web app
that I'm developing. So one scenario of Adaptive Payments would be
like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6uor.gif

In my app the user pays sells his services and receives **100%** of the
payment. My web app will only be able to track the successful payments
and notify the user which product is sold and save the transaction on
user's sales report.

So basically I, The primary receiver will get 0% or $0.01 of the payment and the rest will go to user's PayPal.

Will I be able to receive the IPN notifications to my site with this method?

I just want to get the response back saying whether the payment was
successful and that primary_receiver got $0.01 and secondary_receiver received $40 and other details, so I can store and display them
to the appropriate user. Much like Etsy or other ecommerce sites
work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  When working with Adaptive Payments your app will get an app specific IPN with details pertaining to the app itself and what it just did.

Then, if the receiving account(s) have IPN configured, they would also trigger an IPN for the payment they received.  So, if you are have IPN setup in your Adaptive Payments request and you're also acting as one of the receivers (with IPN configured in your PayPal account) you should expect to get 2 separate IPNs.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That was the answer I needed.